# Cards Bootstrap maquetacion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, card

una consulta, hay algo con lo que siempre batallo a la hora de maquetar algo y son las Cards, nunca recuerdo bien como vendria a ser la extructura de algo, y termino escribiendo codigo de mas (segund yo.) Adjunto las cards que tengo que hacer y como yo las estoy haciendo... tal vez alguien por ahi me pueda dar una mano explicando la estructura de la misma..  La imagen UNO es como tiene que ser, la Imagen DOS  es mi codigo y la imagen TRES es como yo lo estoy haciendo.. (SI puedo usar bootstrap)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <i class="bi bi-calendar2-week d-flex icons fst-normal"
            ><p class="card-text ps-3 text-icons">21 de enero de 2023</p></i
          >
          <i class="bi bi-clock d-flex icons fst-normal">
            <p class="card-text ps-3 text-icons">18:30 hrs.</p></i
          >
          <i class="bi bi-geo-alt-fill d-flex icons fst-normal"
            ><p class="card-text ps-3 text-icons">
              Direccion: Mariano Arista <br />
              200, San Francisco,<br />
              42000 Pachuca de Soto,<br />
              Hgo
            </p></i
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xl-6">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
          <img
            src="./img/Mesa de trabajo 41.png"
            class="card-img-top"
            alt="..."
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

/div>

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido(a) a SOes. El código no debería mostrarse a través de imágenes, recuerda que no todos podemos verlo. Te invito a que edites tu pregunta y pongas el código con su respectivo formato. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas respuestas cuanto antes.

Comment: Estimado no sé qué más se puede decir que no esté en la documentación de bootstrap, que es bastante clara y con muchos ejemplos. Todos los que conozco recurrimos a ella, porque nadie en su sano juicio se aprende todo eso de memoria. Yo recomiendo aprender css grid y flex, y olvidarse de bootstrap: css semántico, sin divitis ni classitis igual a html limpio mantenible y entendible.